# Can Weborb be used to do live video streaming from an iPhone through a media server?

Tags: ios, red5, rtmp, live-streaming, weborb

I am new to multimedia and iOS programming and I came across Weborb while Googling, which provides RTMP library for iOS. It doesn't clearly mention that if it can be used to stream live video through a media server like Red5.

If any one have used this, please let me know that whether it can be used to stream live video from iPhone to a media server and where does it fit in the whole setup. 
Does it act like a server itself between a media server and the iPhone application or does it also have its own media server?

I also want some links for tutorials which can help me start the real coding pertaining to RTMP streaming to a media server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, the RTMP library for iOS can be used with Red5, FMS, WebORB etc. The library is not the server itself, yet client. It establish the RTMP connection to the server and encodes stream before send it to the server.

As I remember the library distributive contains some example to demonstrate how streaming works. Unfortunately, the official site doesn't show any examples related to streaming, the available examples can be useful to start work with the library (http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-mobile/ios-integration/rtmp-ios-examples-integration-between-java-net-and-ios.html). The documentation looks up to date - http://www.themidnightcoders.com/fileadmin/docs/ios/.